# RegEx: Delete all numbers followed by a comma

Tags: regex, mariadb, pcre

I have HTML links in my database which need to be modified.
An example link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/category/subcategory/1,23,456.html">My Link </a>
```

and want to change it to this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/category/subcategory/456.html">My Link </a>
```

I already tried: `/(href=".*)\d+.*,/U` but ended up with only deleting the `1,` form the link. 
My biggest problem is to tell the expression "look for any occurrence of a number followed by a comma, but not a period".

Could anyone assist me with finding a RegEx which is deleting all numbers followed by a comma?
Please keep in mind that these links are within a very big block of HTML code. So the regex must match only on these links.

Comment: [`/\d+,/g`](https://regex101.com/r/EZlCgO/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need to make sure that only numbers with comma are matched within the link. When I modify the pattern to `(href=".*)(\d+,)` it won't work as needed: https://regex101.com/r/EZlCgO/4

Comment: in the regex101 link you selected javascript, what language are you using?

Comment: I just used the one from @Tushar. I am actually using it in MariaDB as tagged in the question. They are using PCRE

Comment: ok i'll update my answer answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regexp

```
(?:(?:^|(?<!\\)").*?href=")(*SKIP)(?!)|\d+,
```

- `(*SKIP)(?!)`

  - `(?!)`: to fail
  - `(*SKIP)`: to avoid backtracking
- `.*?href="`: matches all before first `href="` sequence
- `(?:^|(?<!\\)")` : `^` begin of line anchor or `"` not preceed by `\` and

Note that may not be safe if href can appear outside a tag.

[test with regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EZlCgO/5)

A safier solution using the same technics

```
(?:<![CDATA[.*?]]>|<!--.*?-->|>[^<]*<|href="|"[^">]*(?=>)|(?<!href=)"(?:\\.|[^"])*")(*SKIP)(?!)|\d+,
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working almost perfectly. I had to change `(?<!\\)` to `(?<!\)`. MariaDB seems to work strange in this case, but after the change, it worked. The 2nd modification was that it was not working with `\d+` but worked with `[0-9]+`. I don't know why MariaDB acts like this, but its working now.